# SQL Server :query for exporting to file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to learn the basics of sql programming, I am working with SQL Server 2014. I have managed to import a file into a table with the command:

```
BULK INSERT Db.dbo.Co2_table
FROM 'd:\dataset_co2.txt'
with 
(  
   FIRSTROW =2,  
   ROWTERMINATOR ='\n' 
)
GO
```

I would like to do the dual operation, that is exporting the content of a table to a file. I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\datadump\sqldbdump.txt"
FROM dbo.alarms_2_2014
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


bcp Db.dbo.Co2_table out "C:\users\ws5.en-cre\desktop\prova.txt" -T –c


sqlcmd -S . -d Db -E -s, -W -Q "SELECT * FROM dbo.Co2_table" > ExcelTest.csv
```

But none of these seem to work (I get error messages). Any idea?

Comment: Where did you run those commands from? Management Studio or console?

Comment: ***WHAT*** error messages do you get? Please post the complete and precise messages you've seen ....

Comment: FYI.. you can do a right click on result set to `the save results as`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are running those commands from Management Studio. You should use console for this command.This works for me. Also check if you have permissions on that folder.

```
bcp "select * from Db.dbo.Co2_table" queryout C:\users\ws5.en-cre\desktop\prova.txt  -c -T
```

or

```
bcp Db.dbo.Co2_table out C:\users\ws5.en-cre\desktop\prova.txt  -c -T
```

Also you have suspicious symbol in `c` parameter `-T –c`. It is not a regular dash `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answers and suggestions, and apologies for my lack of precision and my late reply (in this case I missed the notifications from stackoverflow).

Regarding the question on whether I use mstudio or console, what I do is clicking on “new query” from mstudio, write the code and press execute. So I guess the answer is that I use mstudio.

If I try:

```
bcp "select * from Db.dbo.Co2_table" queryout 
C:\users\ws5.en-cre\desktop\prova.txt -c –T
```

it says

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.
```

I guess in this case one of the problem is that the quotes are missing, but even adding them doesn’t solve the problem.

I am looking for a solution that can be implemented as a script. I am familiar with excel vba macros, I would like to implement something like that.

Thanks,

Alex